# Was aurioTouch example supposed to play back sound from the mic?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I ran aurioTouch examole on the iPad.  But I could not hear any echo sound playing back from the mic.   The graphics part is working fine.

Comment: Please make the question clear... what actually u want???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to click on the MUTE BUTTON. Red light need to be off.

[image]